# Remember site permissions

Tags: usb, ubuntu, permissions, troubleshooting

I have a javascript page on a website that needs access to a USB port on the PI.
When I open the page I can grant permission to the site to access the USB port.
But the browser does not remember that access has been granted.
So the next time I open the page I have to grant access again.

I am running Ubuntu 64 bit and the Vivaldi browser on the PI 4 - but have also tried Chromium.

On a PC running Ubuntu or Windows, the browser remembers the permission, so I am blaming the PI
Is there a setting I am missing?

Comment: I don't see how the pi could control what the browser remembers - perhaps the browsers are set up to *forget everything* when closed

Comment: I don't think so but i will try accepting cookies and see if that is persistent

Comment: I never said anything about cookies, so ...

Comment: why would you blame the Pi for something that Linux does?

Comment: because the same thing doesn't happen with Ubuntu on a PC - as far as I can see, the Pi is the only difference between the two setups